# Blank page when connecting to sql server - classic asp

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I need help I am getting a constant blank page when connecting to a database in classic asp. **I have changed some of the connection string for security purposes.** I know this string works because I can connect to it in vb.net.

```
    <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Search Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<% 
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open "Data Source=ServerIP;Initial Catalog=Database;User ID=Username;Password=Password"

strSql = "SELECT * FROM categories Where idParentcategory=1 ORDER BY categorydesc ASC"

Set rs = Conn.Execute(strSql)

If rs.eof Then
   Response.write("No records returned")
End If

do until rs.eof
   Response.write(rs("categorydesc") &  "<br>")
   rs.movenext
loop

Conn.Close
Set Conn = Nothing
 %>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's showing a blank page, is it possible you have an `on error resume next` we can't see (maybe it's in an include file)?

I would handle this by checking for `eof` and then only looping through the resultset *if* it is not empty.

```
Set rs = Conn.Execute(strSql)

If rs.eof Then
  Response.write("No records returned")
Else
  do until rs.eof
    Response.write(rs("categorydesc") &  "<br>")
    rs.movenext
  loop
End If

rs.Close : set rs = nothing
Conn.Close : set Conn = Nothing
```

This isn't really different from @03Usr's answer except:

1. You should be able to determine why the page is coming up blank.
2. In addition to closing and disposing of your connection object, you really should also close and dispose of your recordset object (even if it is empty).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If not rs.eof then
Do while not rs.eof or rs.bof 
      Response.write(rs("categorydesc") &  "<br>")
    rs.movenext
    Loop
 Else
      Response.Write "No records found"
 End If
```